# Load image to markers on maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, marker

I have implemented a simple google map where i display a list of markers depending on a list that i have for that.

To display them i iterate over the list and create each marker, like this:

```
for (final PhotosForPlants p : photos) {
            if (p.getLat() != null && p.getLon() != null && p.getLat() != 0.0 && p.getLon() != 0.0) // check for 0.0
            {
                if (p.getId() == currentPlantId) {
                    plantLocation = new LatLng(p.getLat(), p.getLon());
                    yellowPos = plantLocation;
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(plantLocation, 35f));
                    Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(plantLocation)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));

                    m.setTag(p);
                    markers.add(m);
                } else {
                    plantLocation = new LatLng(p.getLat(), p.getLon());
                    positions.add(plantLocation);
                    positionSave = index;
                    Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(plantLocation)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

                    m.setTag(p);
                    markers.add(m);
                }

            }
            index++;
        }
    }
```

instead of having a simple marker image, i need to have something like a square image loaded from my server, i try to use picasso for it but i don't know if i get any problem doing it this way to get the bitmap:

```
 public void loadBitmap(String url) {

        if (loadtarget == null) loadtarget = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                // do something with the Bitmap
                handleLoadedBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }

        };

        Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(loadtarget);
    }

    public Bitmap handleLoadedBitmap(Bitmap b) {
        return b;
    }
```

my main problem is that i don't know how i can retrive each image loaded for the specific marker, and how to set it ip with my maps :S.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the second part of your question: If you have a Bitmap object you can modify your code with

```
 Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(plantLocation)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(myBitmap)));
```

in order to use myBitmap as the marker.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Marker source = mMap.addMarker(
               new MarkerOptions()
    .position( 
        new LatLng(
            Double.parseDouble(info.getLatitude()), 
            Double.parseDouble(info.getLongitude())))
    .title(info.getBankName())
    .snippet(info.getBankAddress())    
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getBitmap(url))));



 public static Bitmap getBitmap(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        return null;
    }
}
```